# I have a `<p> could be anything </p>` I need the the last word of the text but not the </p>

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `<p> could be anything </p>`  I need the  the last  word of the text but not the `</p>`.

```js
thetag.innerHTML = `<p> timmy:tampa </p>`
let collect=thetag[-1]
```

Comment: Your question will not be better if you repeat same sentence three times

Comment: Use `.textContent` to access the string

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Fetch the string (`innerText`). 2. Make a word array (`split()`) 3. take the last array element (`at()`)

```js
const s = document.querySelector('p').innerText;

console.log(s.split(' ').at(-1));
```

```html
<p> could be anything </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.innerHTML` tag of the `anweaser` paragraph to store the text as a String.
Then just `.split(" ")` by a space or whatever delimiter you need, and grab the last item in the list.